# Crazy og:type Bug in Typoscript Library (content equals og:article)

Tags: typo3, facebook-opengraph, typoscript

I am trying to setup a working data schema for my site and when using a Typoscript snippet that works fine on one site, I am about to give up.

This is the error from google data check:
[image: og:type IS NOT og:article]

As you can see the sourcecode is fine. I quadruple checked this.

Here is the complete library:

```
    page.headerData.3 = COA
    page.headerData.3 {
    4 = TEXT
    4.value = <meta property="og:type" content="article">

    10 = IMG_RESOURCE
    10.file {
        import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = 0
        width=1200
    }
    10.stdWrap.dataWrap = <meta property="og:image" content="{getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_HOST}/|" />
    10.stdWrap.insertData = 1

    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        typolink.parameter.data = TSFE:id
        typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
        typolink.returnLast = url
        wrap = <meta property="og:url" content="|" />
    }

    30 = TEXT
    30.value = Lightningsoul
    30.wrap = <meta property="og:site_name" content="|" />

    40 = TEXT
    40.field = title
    40.wrap = <meta property="og:title" content=" |&nbsp; - renoi.de" />
    40.stdWrap.insertData = 1

    50 = TEXT
    50.field = description
    50.ifEmpty= Renoi ist ein Unternehmen, das Weblösungen wie bspw. Typo3, Wordpress oder Drupal und deren Einrichtung und Weiterentwicklung anbietet.
    50.wrap = <meta property="og:description" content="|" />

}
```

Any hint or is this a core bug in google? THANK YOU!

Here are the URLs to check:
https://lightningsoul.de/artikel/e-sports/hammer-von-sol/ (working example - almost the same typoscript except for static values)

https://renoi.de/blog/webentwicklung/dynamische-scroll-to-library-fuer-typo3-content-elemente/ (does not work)

Using this test:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try instead with

```
page.meta.og:type = article
page.meta.og:type.attribute = property
page.meta.og:title.data = page:title
page.meta.og:title.attribute = property
```

et cetera? It is IMO the right tool for your task (and IMHO more readable than the page.headerData COA)

See:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#meta
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Meta/Index.html#meta

I also performed the same test on the same url you gave and the test about the "Article" object reports 0 errors, 0 warnings and "@type:Article" - I don't see any "nicht definiert type". I can only presume that there is something odd in the Google parser, but I don't know.

Comment: This renders
<meta name="og:type" content="article">
- name and not property which is wrong due to:
http://ogp.me/
?!
But yeah, this does not show og:article, because it does not show up at all in the schema test tool. ;)

Comment: @Lightningsoul of course you are right! I have been too hasty :) I modified my answer (the answer to your correct remark was in documentation, too)

Comment: yes, it now shows up as property. I didn't have time to check the documentation in detail, yesterday so sorry for that.

But it still shows as content="og:website" (I have changed it from article to website to see if the change to page.meta really works or not.

This can not be solved by me, but has to be solved by google instead, right? :(

Or could it be anything else interfering with my markup? Like xhtml, utf-8 or some other stuff... the weird thing is that both pages run in the same Typo3 instance and mostly use the same code.
I also tried to load this TS first.

Comment: I just tried to put just this in an extension template (database):
page = PAGE
page {
    meta.og:type = article
    meta.og:type.attribute = property
}

It still shows up as "og:article" in the testing tool.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
here it seems to work properly, so there is definitely something wrong with google, right?

Comment: I performed the same test on the same url you gave and the test about the "Article" object reports 0 errors, 0 warnings and "@type:Article" - I don't see any "nicht definiert type"

Comment: What? Why? I just tried in incognito mode and Firefox (before I tested in Chrome). It still shows the error for me.

Comment: I really don't know, maybe the Google parser has something odd :) I just suggest you to use the `page.meta` property, as it is IMO the right tool for your task (and IMHO more readable than the `page.headerData COA`)

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. I just tested again on my desktop PC and tablet via LTE (not using my wifi). Still, the error in the google data test shows up for me.
I will however now choose your answer as the correct one and just hope that it is just a bug in google (which somehow only appears to me). Thank you so much for your time and effort! :)

Comment: @Lightningsoul thank you. I integrated my answer with the discussion writings.